# Error when trying to open Power BI (Analysis Services) ADOMD.NET connection using .NET Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, powerbi, ssas, adomd.net

While using the `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.NetCore.retail.amd64` library version `19.26.1.2` (also tried older version) and trying to connect to Power BI dataset using ADOMD.NET connection from .NET Core 3.1 (also tried 3.0) Azure Function app, on the line:

```
adomdConnection.Open();
```

I get this error message:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1.
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient: **This feature is supported for
> a .NET Core client only on Windows systems and requires that the .NET
> Core Desktop framework is installed**.

However, I am running Windows 10 (and Visual Studio 2019) and I'm pretty sure I do have installed the mentioned .NET Core runtime:

```
dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

I've tried searching for this error message but I found nothing.

How can this issue be resolved?